# Accurate computation of KL divergence between binary RVs

Tags: floating-point

I was wondering how one can compute the KL Divergence between two binary distributions (say, with parameters $p$ and $q$ and assume $p < \frac12$ and $q < \frac12$ for simplicity) accurately. The formula is clearly:
\begin{equation}
D(p,q) = p \log \frac{p}{q} + (1-p) \log \frac{1-p}{1-q}.
\end{equation}

However, implementing the above in a computation system with floating point precision (e.g. a C code using `double` variables) would cause some rounding errors: when $p$ and $q$ are too close, the result becomes negative (although its magnitude is very tiny, let's say it is $-1 \times 10^{-18}$). So I guess there should be a better way of computing the Divergence while still keeping the result as accurate as possible.

(P.S. one can always apply an ad-hoc fix like setting the divergence to $0$ whenever $|p-q|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ but I am actually looking for a more clever solution)

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are close one can replace $D(p,q)$ by the first terms of its series expansion in terms of $p-q$, starting with $(p-q)^2/(2q(1-q))$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could found a sort of fix which of course might not be optimal but at least it works good for the range of values I was concerned about:

Let $\delta := p -q$. Then,
\begin{equation}
D(p,q) = p \log\left(1 + \frac{\delta}{q}\right) + \left(1-p\right) \log\left(1 + \frac{\delta}{q-1}\right)
\end{equation}

Now, we can use the accurate implementations of $\log(1+x)$ (ex. `log1p(x)` in standard C math libraries) to compute the two logarithms (for instance, see http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/ for details on accuracy of computing $\log\left(1+x\right)$ for small values of $x$.) This way I never get a negative result.